# Replace all non capitalised words with ruby

Tags: ruby, text, replace, capitalize

I would like to replace all non capitalised words in a text with "-".length of the word.

For instance I have the following Text (German):

> Florian Homm wuchs als Sohn des mittelständischen Handwerksunternehmers Joachim Homm und seiner Frau Maria-Barbara „Uschi“ Homm im hessischen Bad Homburg vor der Höhe auf. Sein Großonkel mütterlicherseits war der Unternehmer Josef Neckermann. Nach einem Studium an der Harvard University, das er mit einem Master of Business Administration an der Harvard Business School abschloss, begann Homm seine Tätigkeit in der US-amerikanischen Finanzwirtschaft bei der Investmentbank Merrill Lynch, danach war er bei dem US-Fondsanbieter Fidelity Investments, der Schweizer Privatbank Julius Bär und dem US-Vermögensverwalter Tweedy Browne....

should be transformed into

> Florian Homm ---- --- Sohn --- ------------ Handwerksunternehmers Joachim Homm --- ------ Frau Maria-Barbara „Uschi“ Homm -- ---------- Bad Homburg --- Höhe ---. ....

Comment: If you can't finish your own example, it's likely too long.

Comment: What about `„word“` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ input.gsub(/\p{L}+/) { |m| m[0] != m[0].upcase ? '-'*m.length : m }
#⇒ "Florian Homm ----- --- Sohn --- ------------------ Handwerksunternehmers..."
```

More clean solution (credits to Cary):

```
▶ input.gsub(/(?<!\p{L})\p{Lower}+(?!\p{L})/) { |m| '-' * m.length }
```

Comment: This problem is harder than it looks. What should `"Upcase-downcase"` be converted to?

Comment: Considering that `m` is a string of letters, is `m[0] != m[0].upcase` not the same as `m[0] == m[0].downcase`? Maybe `m[0] =~ /\p{Lower}/` instead.

Comment: From https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache : `"die Richter/-innen"` and `"Jede(r) Anwältin und Anwalt"`. German can be a weird language!

Comment: @CarySwoveland good catch, I have updated the answer with a derived from your idea version.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
s.split.map { |word| ('A'..'Z').include?(word[0]) ? word : '-' * word.length }.join(' ')
```

Comment: `split` ⇒ `join` has a penalty on huge texts (imagine, what memory amount would consume an array produced on 10G text, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this for small input size:

Basically, I:

1. Split the input string on whitespace character
2. Map the array to either the word itself (if not capitalized) or the word replaced with dashes (if capitalized)
3. join with whitespaces.

Like so

```
s = "Florian Homm wuchs als Sohn des mittelständischen Handwerksunternehmers Joachim Homm und seiner Frau Maria-Barbara „Uschi“ Homm im hessischen Bad Homburg vor der Höhe auf. Sein Großonkel mütterlicherseits war der Unternehmer Josef Neckermann. Nach einem Studium an der Harvard University, das er mit einem Master of Business Administration an der Harvard Business School abschloss, begann Homm seine Tätigkeit in der US-amerikanischen Finanzwirtschaft bei der Investmentbank Merrill Lynch, danach war er bei dem US-Fondsanbieter Fidelity Investments, der Schweizer Privatbank Julius Bär und dem US-Vermögensverwalter Tweedy Browne...."

s.split(/[[:space:]]/).map { |word| word.capitalize == word ? word : '-' * word.length }.join(' ')
```

Does that apply to your problem?

Cheers!

Edit: For a more memory efficient solution you can use regex replace `gsub`, check out this other answer by mudasobwa https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570686/4411941

Comment: `split` ⇒ `join` has a penalty on huge texts (imagine, what memory amount would consume an array produced on 10G text, for instance.)

Comment: This works neither for "Maria-Barbara" nor "„Uschi“". Fun fact : `"„Uschi“".capitalize` is `"„uschi“"` on Ruby 2.3. No idea why!

Comment: Arf, I guess you can change the `word.capitalize == word` by a definition that matches better with German definition of capitalized word.

Comment: @EricDuminil `capitalize` attempts to capitalize the first character, whether or not it's alphabetical, i.e. `„`, not `U`

Comment: I forgot `capitalize` also downcases the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    (?<![[:alpha:]]) # do not match a letter (negative lookbehind)      
    [[:lower:]]      # match a lowercase letter
    [[:alpha:]]*     # match zero or more letters
    /x               # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "Frau Maria-Barbara „Uschi“ Homm im hessischen Bad Homburg vor der Höhe auf."

str.gsub(r) { |m| '-'*m.size }
  #=> "Frau Maria-Barbara „Uschi“ Homm -- ---------- Bad Homburg --- --- Höhe ---."
"die Richter/-innen".gsub(r) { |m| '-'*m.size }
  #=> "--- Richter/------" 
"Jede(r) Anwältin und Anwalt".gsub(r) { |m| '-'*m.size }
  #=> "Jede(-) Anwältin --- Anwalt"
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. With a `)` more, it looks equivalent to @mudasobwa's answer. German is a complex language, and I didn't find any 100% correct answer for this question. There's a table full of weird cases here : https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache `"die Richter/-innen"` is often seen.

Comment: @Eric, thanks for spotting that. It seems to work with the example you gave in your comment and another in a comment on Mudsie's answer. No?

Comment: `"Richter/-innen"` is just one word. I don't think a part of it should be converted to dashes.

Comment: Similarly "Jede(r)" is just one word. It's an article, which means "Jede" or "Jeder", depending on what's coming after.

Comment: @Eric, I give up.

Comment: Ahah! That's what I did too.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This problem is harder than it looks!

This code might be more memory hungry than others, but I dare say it works for a wider range of (weird) German words :

```
def hide_non_capitalized(text)
  text.split(/[[:space:]]/).map do |chars|
    first_letter = chars[/[[:alpha:]]/]
    if first_letter && first_letter == first_letter.downcase
      ## Keep non-letters :
      chars.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,'-')
      ## Replace every character :
      # '-' * chars.size
    else
      chars
    end
  end.join(' ')
end
```

It splits the text into character blocks, and replaces all the letters of a block if its first letter is lowercase. This code requires Ruby 2.4, because `'ä'.upcase` is still `'ä'` up to Ruby 2.3.

## Test

```
puts hide_non_capitalized(text)
#=> Florian Homm ----- --- Sohn --- ----------------- Handwerksunternehmers Joachim Homm --- ------ Frau Maria-Barbara „Uschi“ Homm -- ---------- Bad Homburg --- --- Höhe ---. Sein Großonkel ----------------- --- --- Unternehmer Josef Neckermann. Nach ----- Studium -- --- Harvard University, --- -- --- ----- Master -- Business Administration -- --- Harvard Business School ---------, ------ Homm ----- Tätigkeit -- --- US-amerikanischen Finanzwirtschaft --- --- Investmentbank Merrill Lynch, ------ --- -- --- --- US-Fondsanbieter Fidelity Investments, --- Schweizer Privatbank Julius Bär --- --- US-Vermögensverwalter Tweedy Browne....

hide_none = "Änderung. „Uschi“, Attaché-case Maria-Barbara US-Fondsanbieter. Die Richter/-innen. Jede(r) 1234 \"#+?\""
puts hide_non_capitalized(hide_none)
#=> Änderung. „Uschi“, Attaché-case Maria-Barbara US-Fondsanbieter. Die Richter/-innen. Jede(r) 1234 "#+?"


hide_all = "öfters. „word“ lowercase-Uppercase jede(r) not/exactly/a/word"
puts hide_non_capitalized(hide_all)
#=> ------. „----“ ------------------- ----(-) ---/-------/-/----
```